# pandoc/rmarkdown: make citations compile to \cite instead of \autocite

Tags: r, latex, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

I am using a custom R Markdown Latex Template, and BibTex, but I am having trouble getting the bibliography to work.

With the default pandoc-citeproc I get the error:

```
pandoc-citeproc: Error parsing references: expected [a], encountered Object
```

Which occurs before the .tex file is generated, not during the compilation of the .tex file. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandoc, which doesn't help.

When I add `--biblatex` as a pandoc argument I get a new error that occurs after the .tex file is generated:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.41 We are writing this using LaTeX \autocite
```

If I replace \autocite with \cite in the .tex file it compiles nicely. It would be nice if I could get pandoc/biblatex to use \cite instead of \autocite so I don't have to manually intervene. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I haven't found a solution to this either. I posted a [feature request](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3811) on the pandoc repository.